# CancelKeyPress handler confuses shells (cmd.exe, powershell, and bash)

Tags: c#, .net-core, sigint

Let's consider this brief demo:

```cs
private static readonly CancellationTokenSource CancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        CancelSource.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("CancelKeyPress event handler finished");
    };
    CancelSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Main finished");
}
```

As you can see, the Program is waiting for the cancel event, stating that it does not want to be shut down, waiting one second, printing "Main finished" and exiting.

I would expect the output to be:

```
C:\Users\Benni\source\repos\Test\Test>dotnet run
Hello world!
CancelKeyPress event handler finished
^C
Main finished
C:\Users\Benni\source\repos\Test\Test>
```

But it is:

```
C:\Users\Benni\source\repos\Test\Test>dotnet run
Hello world!
CancelKeyPress event handler finished
^C
C:\Users\Benni\source\repos\Test\Test>Main finished
```

Unfortunately the shells (I tested bash, cmd.exe and powershell) print the CWD (for the next command) before the program has actually finished running! Am I missing something?  Do I have to use `Console.TreatControlCAsInput`, or is this a coreclr bug?

Comment: Works fine on my machine, Win10 and .NETCore v2.2.103.  Might have something to do with all processes attached to the console seeing the Ctrl+C signal.  Best to file at bug at github.com, be sure to describe all versions.

Comment: @HansPassant in which shell did you run dotnet run? Does it still work if you increase the Task.Delay? I am on .NETCore v2.2.105, W10 1809 build 17763.379, if that matters.

Comment: I ran it the way you showed it.  One notable difference, I don't see the ^C echo.  So your console is configured differently from mine and it does look like cmd.exe is told to stop waiting too early.  No real idea what config affects this, might be bash that screws this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a dotnet cli issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/11050